# Atom reinstalls "linter-ui-default" on every launch (Windows)

Tags: atom-editor

Every time I launch Atom it installs the "linter-ui-default" package with a message "Installing linter dependencies". The linter works well, linter UI shows me errors and tips, all ok. But this installation process increases Atom launching time x10 times.

Is there a way to fix this issue (without removing the linter)?
I tried to manually reinstall the "linter-ui-default" package, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

when they asked to install dependencies, i gave the option never. Then it didn't showed up again. Hope it may work without the dependencies

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).